# Go v 1.5 with -linkshared option produces linking error

Tags: go

Go v 1.5.

1) Compile the package worker:

```
go build -buildmode=shared -linkshared
```

2) Install this package

3) Try to compile another package, which imports worker:

```
go build -linkshared
go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: running gcc failed: exit status 1
gcc: error: missing argument to ‘-l’
```

The same command with '**-x --compiler=gccgo**' option produces the following:

```
/usr/bin/gccgo -o $WORK/godev/testgo/_obj/exe/a.out $WORK/godev/testgo/_obj/_go_.o -Wl,-( -m64 -Wl,-) -L/home/user/dev/godev/pkg/gccgo_linux_amd64_fPIC/shlibs -Wl,-rpath=/home/user/dev/godev/pkg/gccgo_linux_amd64_fPIC/shlibs -l -Wl,-E -fPIC
```

Comment: I suggest you to ask on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/golang-nuts) instead because the latter is read by the `gccgo` maintainer (Ian Taylor) which doesn't frequent SO.

Comment: Assuming steps #1 and #2 are a non-main package and that step #2 is `go install` … you do realize that step #1 just does a build and then throws away the results? You'd need to put any flags with the `go install` of step #2.

Comment: In fact, the same happens if I combine steps #1 and #2:
`go install --buildmode=shared -linkshared` 
In that case `go build -linkshared` produces the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/12236/) is a bug on github. It turned out that go tool generated wrong names.